# Are multiple WHERE/AND clauses in MySQL checked sequentially? And are subsequent checks skipped if the first is false?

Tags: mysql, performance

**Scenario**

Let's say I have a MySQL query that contains multiple `WHERE`/`AND` clauses.

For for instance, say I have the query

```
SELECT * FROM some_table
WHERE col1 = 5
AND col2 = 9
AND col3 LIKE '%string%'
```

**Question**

Is the `col1 = 5` check done as the first in sequence here, since it's written first? And more importantly, are the other two checks skipped if `col1 != 5`?

The reason I ask is that the third clause, `col3 LIKE '%string3%`, will take more time to run, and I'm wondering if it makes sense to put it last, since I don't want to run it if one of the first two checks are false.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL optimizer looks at the query at whole and tries to determine the most optimal query plan for the query. The order of the contitions in where-clause does not matter.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to hear, thanks! I couldn't find this info in the docs though. Can you point me to it?

Answer (score 1):

The optimal index for *that* query is

```
INDEX(col1, col2)   -- in either order
```

Given that, it will definitely check both `col1` and `col2` *simultaneously* in order to whittle down the number of rows to a much smaller number.  Hence the `LIKE` will happen only for the few rows that match both col1 and col2.  *This* order of actions is very likely to be optimal.

Often, it is better (though not identical) to use `FULLTEXT(col3)` and have

```
WHERE col1 = 5
  AND col2 = 9
  AND MATCH(col3) AGAINST ("+string" IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

In this case, I am pretty sure it will start with the FULLTEXT index to test col3, hoping to get very few rows to double check against the other clauses.  Because of various other issues, *this* is optimal.  Any index(es) on `col1` and `col2` will not be used.

The general statement (so far) is:  The Optimizer will pick `AND` clause(s) that it can use for one `INDEX` first.  In that sense, the order of the `AND` clauses is violated -- as an optimization.

If you don't have any suitable indexes, well, shame on you.

There are *many* possibilities.  I will be happy to discuss individual queries, but it will be hard to make too many generalities.